# extend Block\Catalog\Product\List in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to give namespace for Block\Catalog\Product\List in magento 2

```
namespace Lesson\Chapter\Block\Catalog\Product\List;

class Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar 
{
  protected $tglssearchHelper;

  public function __construct(
     \Lesson\Chapter\Helper\Data $tglssearchHelper
   ) {
         $this->tglssearchHelper = $tglssearchHelper;
     }
 }
```

1) Since List is a keyword in php im unable to create a namespace.

```
    2) Also how to give the class path of List Toolbar since Magento 2 
       does not have this Block/Product/List/Toolbar class.


    i get  syntax error, unexpected 'List' (T_LIST), expecting identifier   
 (T_STRING) in \Block\Catalog\Product\List\Toolbar.php on line 2
```

Answer (score 0):

List is a restricted PHP word.

You cannot use any of the following words as constants, class names, function or method names.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

To answer your question, you will have to change your list class name to something else. MyList, CarList, Listing, etc.